# Reading data size in file from byte to byte

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

Assume I want to download 50MB file in 10MB chunks. In a previous session I have downloaded 8MB, so not even one chunk was completed. I want to verify how many bytes are in the file in the range from x to x bytes. So reading data from 0 to 10485759 bytes would give me this 8MB and not 10MB like the below function. Any advice?

I am using this method for something different but this will always return the full size of a chunk:

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path withStartOffset:(off_t)startOffset andEndOffset:(off_t)endOffset
{
    FILE *file = fopen([path UTF8String], "rb");
    if(file == NULL)
        return nil;
    uint64_t size = (endOffset - startOffset) + 1;
    void *data = malloc(size);  // check for NULL!
    fseeko(file, startOffset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, 1, size, file);  // check return value, in case read was short!
    fclose(file);

    // NSData takes ownership and will call free(data) when it's released
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:size];
}
```

Comment: I think the answer is already given in your comment: *"check return value, in case read was short!"*

Comment: Dumb as a stump, thanks mate! :D